# Algorithm for Fuzzy compare of like datasets

Tags: c++, fuzzy-logic

I am looking for an Algorithm/Method for the fuzzy comparison of small like datasets (x,y of world coordinates and sensor angle etc)
Basically I am developing an autonomous mapping robot that seeks the edges and objects in its environment and because of small amounts of jitter in the drive train and Time of Flight sensor returned distance. The system identifies several points that are in fact the same point or edge, so I would like to do a fuzzy compare of a pair of datasets to see if they are the same.
Any ideas or code would be most welcome.
Many thanks imk

Comment: You should provide more info.

Comment: define distance functions for your data and allow for some distance, e.g., if the data is numerical, use an allowed delta for comparing, for x/y coordinates euclidean distance is probably more appropriate, if they are strings, allow for a certain Levenshtein distance between them...